# Login Google javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, google-plus

I´m using google login javascript.

I want import js after click button. The problem: Only show popup login google the second time I click the button

My Code:

```
function clickButton(){
   $.getScript( "https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=onLoadGoogleLogin");
}


 function onLoadGoogleLogin()
            {
                  var initializedGoogleCallback = false;
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyBhV6vP_D_I7ldL1YIU7LJUGtSxJ55ievw');

    var myParams = {
        'callback': function googleLoginCallback(result) {
            debugger;
            if (!initializedGoogleCallback) {
                if (result) {
                    if (result['error'] == undefined) {
                        initializedGoogleCallback = true;
                        gapi.auth.setToken(result);
                        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                            var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
                            request.execute(googleLoginDataUserCallback);
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Empty authResult');
                }
            }
        },
        'clientid': 'xxxxx-4kragpsm6jolann6d9t74crpkthch0iq.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
        'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
            }
```

Comment: Why the second time? Also do note that your code cannot be reproduced without a valid clientId. -- or -- is the  problem that it only show the thing after you click it twice?

Comment: Tommie I update the code. I put de clientId. The problem it only show popup google login after I click it twice

Comment: I see, it's a problem that has to do with you trying to use the script before it has been loaded. :)

Comment: But I load the script using: $.getScript( "https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=onLoadGoogleLogin");

Comment: i see -- it has a special callback. :)

Comment: Then, Does not work? Or Is there another way to load script after  button click?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is failing for you since i don't have the complete script. This is how i would do it: https://jsbin.com/zaguma/3/edit?html,js,console,output  -- but this does not really show anything of course.

Comment: If I put  'approvalprompt': 'force', work for me, but I don´t want request aprroval. In the end function onLoadGoogleLogin, put  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);

Comment: Can't get this to work properly at all, but one revelation is that if one uses focus instead of 'click' the effect your mentioning is gone: https://jsbin.com/zaguma/6/edit?html,css,js,console,output  -- note that this example doesn't entirely work but at least the need to double-click is gone. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Getting Started with Google Sign-In OAuth: A Step-by-Step Guide for Web Developers**

1. Create a Google API Console Project:
   Go to the Google API Console: Google Cloud Platform
   Create a new project by clicking on the "Select a project" dropdown at the top of
   the page and then clicking on "New Project".
   Give your project a name and click on "Create".
2. Enable the Google Identity Platform API:
   From the dashboard, click on “Enable APIs and Services” and search for “Google
   Identity Platform API”.
   Click on “Enable” to enable the API for your project.
3. Create OAuth Credentials:
   Click on “Credentials” in the left-hand menu.
   Click on “Create Credentials” and select “OAuth client ID”.
   Choose “Web application” as the application type and give your client ID a name.
   Add your authorized JavaScript origins and redirect URIs. These should match the
   domain and paths of your web application.
   Click on “Create” to create your OAuth client ID.
4. Add the Google Sign-In API to your web page:
   Add the following script tag to the head section of your web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'> 
    <title>Google Sign in</title> 
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> 
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script> 
    <script> 
        function onSignIn(googleUser) { 
            const responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(googleUser.credential); 
            let google_email = responsePayload.email 
            console.log("google_email - ",google_email) 
        } 
        function decodeJwtResponse(data) { 
            let tokens = data.split("."); 
            return JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1])) 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="login"> 
        <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="enter-your-client-id" 
            data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="popup" data-login_uri="" data-callback="onSignIn" 
            data-itp_support="true"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="rectangular" data-theme="outline" data-text="signin" 
            data-size="large" data-logo_alignment="left"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

find out code : GitHub - https://github.com/Sravankumarraju/googleSignin

Comment: the code provided is not just a script but a complete html page